# Problema com API do facebook

Tags: php, facebook

No site, estou usando a API do facebook para fazer login, só que quando tento fazer login através do botão do facebook aparece essa mensagem:

> Não é possível carregar a URL: O domínio dessa URL não está incluído
>   nos domínios do aplicativo. Para poder carregar essa URL, adicione
>   todos os domínios e subdomínios ao campo Domínios do aplicativo nas
>   configurações do aplicativo.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Você tem que ir nas configurações do App no Facebook e adicionar seu domínio lá. Se não me engano não funciona `http://localhost`. Deve ser um domínio mesmo.

Comment: @Gumball configurações? no meu código mesmo?

Comment: Não. Lá aonde você criou seu APP no Facebook. Você chegou a criar um App ?

Comment: Então usei a api no netbeans para fazer login no site a partir do facebook. @Gumball

Comment: Entendi... Mas acho que você tem que ter um APP criado no Facebook para se logar nele. Porquê eu fiz isso em um sistema.

Comment: Sim, você deve acessar facebook apps, criar o app e definir um dominio (www.seuapp.com.br por exemplo), desta forma a integração SOMENTE irá aceitar requests do domínio especificado.

Answer (score 10):

Você deve selecionar o dominio para o App, se você estiver no `localhost`, basta colocar o `localhost` como o dominio do app, se não coloque o dominio que tenta acessar:
[image: Basta escrever o dominio no campo App Domains]

Espero ter ajudado!